# How can i loop every Map to extract the images links from it?

Tags: c#, winforms

In form1 i have this code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=0&continent=europa#", localFilename + "Sat24_Temperature_Europe.html");
                client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=1&continent=europa#", localFilename + "Sat24_Rain_Europe.html");
                client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=2&continent=europa#", localFilename + "Sat24_Wind_europe.html");
                client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=3&continent=europa#", localFilename + "Sat24_Lightnings_Europe.html");
                client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=4&continent=europa#", localFilename + "Sat24_Cloudtypes_Europe.html");
                client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/?ir=true&ra=true&li=false", localFilename + "Sat24_Cloudsheight_Europe.html");
                client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/en/eu?ir=true", localFilename + "Sat24_Satellite_Europe.html");
            }
            MapsToRead = Directory.GetFiles(localFilename, "*.*");
            for (int i = 0; i < MapsToRead.Length; i++)
            {
                string s = File.ReadAllText(MapsToRead[i]);
                Maps.Add(s);
            }
            StartTags = new List<string>();
            StartTags.Add("image2.ashx"); 
            StartTags.Add("http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx"); 
            LastTags = new List<string>();
            LastTags.Add("ra=true");
            LastTags.Add("cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa");
            LastTags.Add("ir=true");
```

Since the tags in the html files in most cases are the same i added to the StartTags and LastTags only the tags that are needed.

Now in the new class i have a method im doing:

```
public ExtractImages(List<string> FirstTags, List<string> LastTags, List<string> Maps, string LocalFileDir, string UrlsDir)
        {
            localdir = LocalFileDir;
            counter = 0;
            imagesSatelliteUrls = new List<string>();
            imagesRainUrls = new List<string>();
            int startIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = 0;
            int position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < FirstTags.Count; i++)
            {
                string startTag = FirstTags[i];
                string endTag = LastTags[i];
                startIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(startTag);
                while (startIndex > 0)
                {

                    endIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(endTag, startIndex);
                    if (endIndex == -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    string t = Maps[i].Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + endTag.Length);
                    imagesSatelliteUrls.Add(t);
```

Before i did the changes with the tags in Form1 i just added to each tag List the same tags 7 times since the List Maps contain 7 indexs.
And then in the new calls when im doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < FirstTags.Count; i++)
```

So FirstTags contained 7 indexs LastTags contained 7 indexs and Maps contain 7 indexs.
But now after the changes FirstTags contain 2 index and LastTags contain 3 indexs.
And Maps contain 7 indexs.

How can i do the FOR loop now so it will run through all the 7 Maps and use the tags for each map.

For example for Maps[0] the StartTag is "image2.ashx"
But for Maps[1] and [2] and [4] [5] and [6] its the same Tag:  "http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx"

Same thing for the LastTags.

This is how the tags in Form1 now:

```
StartTags = new List<string>();
StartTags.Add("image2.ashx"); 
StartTags.Add("http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx"); 
LastTags = new List<string>();
LastTags.Add("ra=true");
LastTags.Add("cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa");
LastTags.Add("ir=true");
```

And this is how it was in the old version before i changed it:

```
StartTags = new List<string>();
            StartTags.Add("image2.ashx"); 
            StartTags.Add("http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx"); // Cloudstypes forecast map of europe
            StartTags.Add("http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx"); // Lightnings forecast map of europe
            StartTags.Add("image2.ashx"); // Satellite map of europe
            StartTags.Add("http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx"); // Rain forecast map of europe
            StartTags.Add("http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx"); // Temperature forecast map of europe
            StartTags.Add("http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx"); // Wind forecast map of europe
            LastTags = new List<string>();
            LastTags.Add("ra=true"); // Cloudsheight forecast map of europe
            LastTags.Add("cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa"); // Cloudstypes forecast map of europe
            LastTags.Add("cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa"); // Lightnings forecast map of europe
            LastTags.Add("ir=true"); // Satellite map of europe
            LastTags.Add("cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa"); // Rain forecast map of europe
            LastTags.Add("cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa"); // Temperature forecast map of europe
            LastTags.Add("cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa"); // Wind forecast map of europe
```

Since some of the tags most of them are the same i changed it but now how do i make the FOR loop in the new class since each List have another amount of indexs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to **condense** your lists that way. Because the strings in `.NET` are **immutable** and they are optimized by the compiler. All the same string objects will point to the same memory storing the string value. Your old `List` of course will have more references to point to the memory storing the string values than the new **condensed one**. BUT that's very very little. If you want to avoid duplicated code used to add items to your `Lists` you can try using some `Enumerable.Repeat` method like this:

```
StartTags = new List<string>();
StartTags.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat("http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx",7));
StartTags[0] = StartTags[3] = "image2.ashx";

LastTags = new List<string>();
LastTags.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat("cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa",7));
LastTags[0] = "ra=true";
LastTags[3] = "ir=true";
```